# After Adding a Simple Product to Woocommerce there are not a buy button on the page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My problem is rather strange. After adding the product it is impossible to buy from web site page. There simply does not appear a buy button.

I tried many options. But the button never appeared. At the same time, when adding a variable product, there is no such problem.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: What is the price of the product?

Comment: I thought about it. I also thought that the client forgets to add the price. But no, I added the price. http://prntscr.com/ob108d

Comment: Here is one more screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ob14zx

Comment: By the way you can add it to your question. Just copy and paste with Cmd + C

Comment: Please enter var_dump($price); between the <?php and the if(....; reload the page and send another screenshot of it. And is your page reachable for me from the internet?

Comment: I added var_dump($price);  and I see very interestin image.
https://www.nano-jewelry.co.il/product/title/

Comment: So it looks like that your $price is undefined. This is the reason why there is no place order button. Please show a screenshot of this product in the backend.,

Comment: Yes, I see. the $price is really undefined. http://prntscr.com/ob1gid Strange behavior.

Comment: Maybe you can share the code of the file we used to var_dump the price? Maybe here if not on StackOverflow: https://codeshare.io/

Comment: Yes here is the code: https://codeshare.io/G8oNDJ 
The 249 line is including <?php if($price > 0): ?>  this code line

Comment: Please write me on skype: jaika113

Comment: I just removed this condition:  <?php if($price > 0): ?> I thought once because of <?php if($price > 0): ?> it is impossible to display the buttons I will do it without this condition. But not. Buttons actually appeared but they did not work. And I saw this weird id: http://prntscr.com/ob1uq2 It feels like the product should be associated with variations.